# How to use algolia with firstore flutter?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, algolia

I am trying to deploy some cloud functions using algolia search but it gives me some errors.
When deleting this line:
`const algoliasearch = require('algoliasearch')` and functions that related to algolia, it deploys successfully.

The error is:

```
=== Deploying to 'ecommerce-8e525'...

    i  deploying functions
    +  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
    i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
    i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
    +  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
    +  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
    i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
    i  functions: packaged functions (2.92 KB) for uploading
    +  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully

The following functions are found in your project but do not exist in your local source code:
        onCreateSection(us-central1)
        onDeleteCategory(us-central1)
        onDeleteSection(us-central1)
        onUpdateCategory(us-central1)
        onUpdateSection(us-central1)

If you are renaming a function or changing its region, it is recommended that you create the new function first before deleting the old one to prevent event loss.
For more info, visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#modify

? Would you like to proceed with deletion? Selecting no will continue the rest of the deployments. No
    i  functions: creating Node.js 14 function onCreateSubCategory(us-central1)...
    i  functions: creating Node.js 14 function onUpdateSubCategory(us-central1)...
    i  functions: creating Node.js 14 function onDeleteSubCategory(us-central1)...
    i  functions: creating Node.js 14 function onUpdateMainCategory(us-central1)...
    i  functions: creating Node.js 14 function onDeleteMainCategory(us-central1)...
    i  functions: updating Node.js 14 function onDeleteProduct(us-central1)...
    i  functions: updating Node.js 14 function onCreateCustomer(us-central1)...
    i  functions: updating Node.js 14 function onUpdateCustomer(us-central1)...
    i  functions: updating Node.js 14 function onDeleteCustomer(us-central1)...
    i  functions: cleaning up build files...

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        onCreateSubCategory(us-central1)
        onDeleteCustomer(us-central1)
        onCreateCustomer(us-central1)
        onUpdateSubCategory(us-central1)
        onUpdateCustomer(us-central1)
        onUpdateMainCategory(us-central1)
        onDeleteProduct(us-central1)
        onDeleteSubCategory(us-central1)
        onDeleteMainCategory(us-central1)

To try redeploying those functions, run:
    firebase deploy --only "functions:onCreateSubCategory,functions:onDeleteCustomer,functions:onCreateCustomer,functions:onUpdateSubCategory,functions:onUpdateCustomer,functions:onUpd
ateMainCategory,functions:onDeleteProduct,functions:onDeleteSubCategory,functions:onDeleteMainCategory"

To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
    firebase deploy --except functions

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.
```

This is my code:

```js
    const functions = require("firebase-functions");
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    const algoliasearch = require('algoliasearch');

    const ALGOLIA_APP_ID = "APP_ID";
    const ALGOLIA_ADMIN_KEY = "ADMIN_KEY";
    const ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME = "users";

    admin.initializeApp();
    const storage = admin.storage();

    // When admin create sub category:
    exports.onCreateSubCategory = functions.firestore
        .document("/subCategories/{subCategoryId}")
        .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {

            const createdSubCategory = snapshot.data();

            const subCategoryId = context.params.subCategoryId;

            const mainCategoryId = createdSubCategory['main_category_id'];

            // add it to main category

            admin
                .firestore()
                .collection("mainCategories")
                .doc(mainCategoryId).update({
                    'sub_categories_ids': admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(subCategoryId)
                });

        });

    // When admin update sub category:

    exports.onUpdateSubCategory = functions.firestore.document("/subCategories/{subCategoryId}").onUpdate(async (change, context) => {

        const updatedSubCategoryData = change.after.data();

        const oldSubCategoryData = change.before.data();

        const productsRef =  admin.firestore().collection('products');

        // case of updating image
        // delete old image from storage

        var oldImage = oldSubCategoryData['image_id'];

          const bucket = storage.bucket();
          const path = "subCategories/" + oldImage;
          await bucket.file(path).delete();

          // case of updating name
        // update sub category name for related products
        const productsQuerySnapshot = await productsRef.where('sub_category', '==', oldSubCategoryData['name']).get();
        productsQuerySnapshot.forEach(doc => {

          productsRef.doc(doc.id).update({
            "sub_category": updatedSubCategoryData['name'],
            "categories": admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(oldSubCategoryData['name']),
            "categories": admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(updatedSubCategoryData['name']),
            })

        })

    })

     // When admin delete sub category:
     exports.onDeleteSubCategory = functions.firestore.document("/subCategories/{subCategoryId}").onDelete(async (snapshot, context) => {

         const subCategoryData = snapshot.data();

         const imageId = subCategoryData['image_id'];

         console.log('image_id is ',imageId);

          // 1- delete sub category image from storage

          const bucket = storage.bucket();
          const path = "subCategories/" + imageId;
          await bucket.file(path).delete();

        // 2- delete sub category from products
        const productsRef =  admin.firestore().collection('products');
        const productsQuerySnapshot = await productsRef.where('sub_category', '==', subCategoryData['name']).get();
        productsQuerySnapshot.forEach( async doc => {

        await productsRef.doc(doc.id).update({
           'sub_category': {},
           'categories': admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(subCategoryData['name'])
         })

       })

     })

    //4) when admin update main category
    exports.onUpdateMainCategory = functions.firestore.document("/mainCategories/{mainCategoryId}").onUpdate(async (change, context) => {

        const updatedMainCategoryData = change.after.data();

        const oldMainCategoryData = change.before.data();

        const mainCategoryId = context.params.mainCategoryId;

        //1- when admin change main category name

        /// change main category name for related products

        const productsRef =  admin.firestore().collection('products');
        const productsQuerySnapshot = await productsRef.where('categories', 'array-contains', oldMainCategoryData['name']).get();

        productsQuerySnapshot.forEach( async doc =>{
          await productsRef.doc(doc.id).update({
              'categories': FieldValue.arrayRemove(oldMainCategoryData['name']),
              'categories': admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(updatedMainCategoryData['name'])
        })


        })

        //2- when admin remove subCategory
        /// delete them from subCategories collection

        const oldSubCategoriesIds = oldMainCategoryData['sub_categories_ids'];

        const updatedSubCategories = updatedMainCategoryData['sub_categories_ids'];


        let difference = oldSubCategoriesIds.filter(x => !updatedSubCategories.includes(x));

        difference.forEach(async id =>{
          await admin.firestore().collection('subCategories').doc(id).delete();

        })


    })


    // 5) when admin delete main category
    exports.onDeleteMainCategory = functions.firestore.document("/mainCategories/{mainCategoryId}").onDelete(async (snapshot, context) => {

        const mainCategoryData = snapshot.data();

        const subCategoriesIds = mainCategoryData['sub_categories_ids'];


        // delete category from products

        const productsRef = admin.firestore().collection('products');
        const productsQuerySnapshot = await productsRef.where('categories', 'array-contains', mainCategoryData['name']).get();

        productsQuerySnapshot.forEach(async doc =>{
           await productsRef.doc(doc.id).update({
              'categories': admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(mainCategoryData['name'])
          })

        })


        // delete sub categories

        subCategoriesIds.forEach(async id =>{

         await admin.firestore().collection('subCategories').doc(id).delete();
        })

    })


    // 6) when admin delete product
    exports.onDeleteProduct = functions.firestore.document("/products/{productId}").onDelete(async (snapshot, context) => {

        const categoryData = snapshot.data();

        const imageId = categoryData['image_id'];

        // delete it's image from storage
        const bucket = storage.bucket();
        const path = "products/" + imageId;
        return bucket.file(path).delete();

    })


       // 7) onCreate Customer
        exports.onCreateCustomer = functions.firestore
            .document('users/{userId}')
            .onCreate( async (snap, context) => {
                const newValue = snap.data();
                newValue.objectID = snap.id;

                var client = algoliasearch(ALGOLIA_APP_ID, ALGOLIA_ADMIN_KEY);

                var index = client.initIndex(ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME);
                index.saveObject(newValue);
                console.log("Finished");
            });

            // 8) onUpdate Customer
        exports.onUpdateCustomer = functions.firestore
            .document('users/{userId}')
            .onUpdate( async (snap, context) => {
                const afterUpdate = snap.after.data();
                afterUpdate.objectID =  snap.after.id;

                var client = algoliasearch(ALGOLIA_APP_ID, ALGOLIA_ADMIN_KEY);

                var index = client.initIndex(ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME);
                index.saveObject(afterUpdate);
            });

            // 9) onDelete Customer
        exports.onDeleteCustomer = functions.firestore
            .document('users/{userId}')
            .onDelete( async (snap, context) => {
                const oldID = snap.id;
                var client = algoliasearch(ALGOLIA_APP_ID, ALGOLIA_ADMIN_KEY);

                var index = client.initIndex(ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME);
                index.deleteObject(oldID);
            });
```

**Edit I tried to run with "firebase deploy --only function --debug and this is the result "**

```
Functions deploy had errors with the following functions: onCreateSubCategory(us-central1) onDeleteCustomer(us-central1) onDeleteProduct(us-central1) onCreateCustomer(us-central1) onDeleteMainCategory(us-central1) onUpdateMainCategory(us-central1) onUpdateCustomer(us-central1) onDeleteSubCategory(us-central1) onUpdateSubCategory(us-central1) To try redeploying those functions, run: firebase deploy --only "functions:onCreateSubCategory,functions:onDeleteCustomer,functions:onDeleteProduct,functions:onCreateCustomer,functions:onDeleteMainCategory,functions:onUpd ateMainCategory,functions:onUpdateCustomer,functions:onDeleteSubCategory,functions:onUpdateSubCategory" To try redeploying those functions, run: firebase deploy --only "functions:onCreateSubCategory,functions:onDeleteCustomer,functions:onDeleteProduct,functions:onCreateCustomer,functions:onDeleteMainCategory,functions:onUpdateMainCategory,functions: onUpdateCustomer,functions:onDeleteSubCategory,functions:onUpdateSubCategory"

To continue deploying other features (such as database), run: firebase deploy --except functions [2021-07-31T19:29:21.057Z] Error during update for projects/ecommerce-8e525/locations/us-central1/functions/onCreateSubCategory: firebase deploy --only "functions:onCreateSubCategory,functions:onDeleteCustomer,functions:onDeleteProduct,functions:onCreateCustomer,functions:onDeleteMainCategory,functions:onUpdateMainCategory,functions: onUpdateCustomer,functions:onDeleteSubCategory,functions:onUpdateSubCategory" To continue deploying other features (such as database), run: firebase deploy --except functions [2021-07-31T19:29:21.057Z] Error during update for projects/ecommerce-8e525/locations/us-central1/functions/onCreateSubCategory: [2021-07-31T19:29:21.058Z] Error during update for projects/ecommerce-8e525/locations/us-central1/functions/onDeleteCustomer: [2021-07-31T19:29:21.058Z] Error during update for projects/ecommerce-8e525/locations/us-central1/functions/onDeleteProduct: [2021-07-31T19:29:21.058Z] Error during update for projects/ecommerce-8e525/locations/us-central1/functions/onCreateCustomer: [2021-07-31T19:29:21.058Z] Error during update for projects/ecommerce-8e525/locations/us-central1/functions/onDeleteMainCategory: [2021-07-31T19:29:21.058Z] Error during update for projects/ecommerce-8e525/locations/us-central1/functions/onUpdateMainCategory: [2021-07-31T19:29:21.058Z] Error during update for projects/ecommerce-8e525/locations/us-central1/functions/onUpdateCustomer: firebase deploy --only "functions:onCreateSubCategory,functions:onDeleteCustomer,functions:onDeleteProduct,functions:onCreateCustomer,functions:onDeleteMainCategory,functions:onUpd ateMainCategory,functions:onUpdateCustomer,functions:onDeleteSubCategory,functions:onUpdateSubCategory"

To continue deploying other features (such as database), run: firebase deploy --except functions [2021-07-31T19:29:21.057Z] Error during update for projects/ecommerce-8e525/locations/us-central1/functions/onCreateSubCategory: [2021-07-31T19:29:21.058Z] Error during update for projects/ecommerce-8e525/locations/us-central1/functions/onDeleteCustomer: [2021-07-31T19:29:21.058Z] Error during update for projects/ecommerce-8e525/locations/us-central1/functions/onDeleteProduct: [2021-07-31T19:29:21.058Z] Error during update for projects/ecommerce-8e525/locations/us-central1/functions/onCreateCustomer: [2021-07-31T19:29:21.058Z] Error during update for projects/ecommerce-8e525/locations/us-central1/functions/onDeleteMainCategory: [2021-07-31T19:29:21.058Z] Error during update for projects/ecommerce-8e525/locations/us-central1/functions/onUpdateMainCategory: [2021-07-31T19:29:21.058Z] Error during update for projects/ecommerce-8e525/locations/us-central1/functions/onUpdateCustomer: [2021-07-31T19:29:21.059Z] Error during update for projects/ecommerce-8e525/locations/us-central1/functions/onDeleteSubCategory: [2021-07-31T19:29:21.059Z] Error during update for projects/ecommerce-8e525/locations/us-central1/functions/onUpdateSubCategory:

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: I can't see code for `onCreateSection`

Comment: sorry I had edtied it , now it is ready . @Dharmaraj

Comment: There are some issues with code. Like you cannot use await inside of forEach loop and await is missing in some cases. Can you run `firebase deploy --only function --debug` to get debug logs?

Comment: Error: Cannot understand what targets to deploy/serve. No targets in firebase.json match '--only function'. If you are using PowerShell make sure you place quotes
around any comma-separated lists (ex: --only "functions,firestore").  @Dharmaraj

Comment: I think you forgot 's' in 'functions' . @Dharmaraj

Comment: Yes, functions*

Comment: "firebase deploy --only function --debug " result below @Dharmaraj

Comment: this line  "const algoliasearch = require('algoliasearch');"  cause the problem

Comment: How do you know it's that line? Can you share a screenshot of any error you've spotted there?

Comment: Before adding this line it deployed successfully and when deleting it . No Additional Screenshot for other errors . @Dharmaraj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove these installations and reinstall again solves the problem .

1. `npm install -g firebase-tools`
2. `firebase login`
3. `firebase init`
4. `cd functions`
5. `npm install algoliasearch --save`
6. `firebase functions:config:set algolia.appid="YOUR_APP_ID" algolia.apikey="YOUR_API_KEY"`